# Passenger works standalone fails in apache2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Complete newb to rails & passenger.
I'm running passenger 3.0.19 on Linux Mint.  My app runs fine with WEBrick(rails server) and with standalone passenger.  When I try to use mod_passenger I get "FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "me_user" (PG::Error)":

```
#Phusion Passenger config info
LoadModule passenger_module /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-3.0.19
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1

#Suppose you have a Rails application in /somewhere. Add a virtual host to your
#Apache configuration file and set its DocumentRoot to /somewhere/public:

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp/public
  <Directory /var/www/myapp/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I should note: that the db account works via commandline and is configured in database.yml.  I've seen ppl indicate that this is an issue with pg_hba.conf...but if that were my problem then the application wouldn't work in standalone either...but it does.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you usually have to specify Passenger's Rails environment in the Directory tag? Like `RailsEnv production`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your pg_hba.conf, I can take a guess from my own fun experience with getting Postgres to work properly with mod_rails. Make sure you have:

```
host: localhost
```

in your database.yml. This will affect how Rails attempts to connect to the database.

Also, please ensure that in testing using the psql client, you are able to do so while impersonating the user that is running mod_rails. For example, if this user is named "passenger":

```
sudo -u passenger psql -h localhost -U <db_user> -d <db name>
```

If this doesn't work, please post appropriately redacted database.yml and pg_hba.conf and I can take a look at those.

Comment: sudo: unknown user: passenger -- i guess this is my problem?

Comment: my apache is running as www-data.  The command works with sudo -u www-data psql -h localhost -U ...

Answer (score 0):

database.yml (Note: test and development are defined exactly like production)

> production:
>
> adapter: postgresql
>
> encoding: unicode
>
> database: mydb
>
> pool: 5
>
> username: myuser
>
> password: pwd

pg_hba.conf:

> # Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
>   local   all             postgres                                peer
>
> # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
>
> local   all             all                                     peer
>
> # IPv4 local connections:
>
> host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
>
> # IPv6 local connections:
>
> host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

thanks mikeryz!